# Find the range of $g(2)$ using the given data.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Let $g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$, where $f$ is such that $\frac 12 \le f(t) \le 1$ for $0\le t\le 1$ and $0\le f(t)\le \frac 12$ for $1\le t\le 2$. Find range of $g(2)$

$$g(2) =\int_{0}^{2} f(t) dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}f(t) dt +\int_{1}^{2} f(t) dt$$

How do I find the range from here?

Edit: Simply plugging the maximum value for each integral will given $1/2$ and $3/2$ as max and min value respectively. This is not the right answer

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum value that $f$ can take? What are the corresponding integrals?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan that would given $1/2$ and $3/2$, which is not the right answer

Comment: I don't see how you can get $g(2) = 0$, probably a typo in the answer - since $f(t) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ in $[0,1]$, and is still non negative in $[1,2]$, it must be at least $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan so is my answer correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$1/2 \le \int_{0}^{1}f(t) dt \le 1$$

and

$$0 \le \int_{1}^{2} f(t) dt \le 1/2.$$

Comment: Answer is $(0,2)$

Comment: @Aditya no way that this integral can be $2$. Even if $f(t)$ was constant $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $1/2$ on $[1,2]$ the integral is $3/2$. The result is $[1/2,3/2]$

Comment: Alright then. So the answer is put is correct right?